# node.js soap sample client fails to run

Tags: node.js, soap, client

```
node client_soap.js 

node.js:249
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module './http'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:333:15)
    at Function._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a1/mysourc3e/client_soap.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:309:12)
    at module.js:482:10

npm list
/home/a1/mysourc3e
└─┬ soap@0.1.3 
  ├── node-expat@1.5.0 
  └── request@2.2.6
```

I'm trying to run a sample code for node.js with soap.
I can't get https://github.com/milewise/node-soap/blob/master/lib/client.js to work.
Where do I get the module from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `require('http')` instead of `require('./http')`.

The [HTTP module is built in to node](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http), so you shouldn't tell the loader to look for it in the current directory (as the "`./`" prefix does).